# LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have gone through the spring data jpa reference documentation
to configure a datasource in spring boot,and with LocalcontainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and transactionManager..etc,but run it 
with error

but I want configure a datasource of mysql,single datasource.
this is configuration class code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataSourceConfig {

   @Bean

   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="oneslide.datasource")
   public DataSource dataSource() {

       return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
   }

   @Bean 
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
       HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendor=new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

       vendor.setGenerateDdl(true);

       LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory=new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

       factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendor);

       factory.setPackagesToScan("com.oneslide.multiDataSource.domain");

       factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

       return factory;

   }

   @Bean 
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
       JpaTransactionManager transactionManager=new JpaTransactionManager();
       transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
       return transactionManager;
   }
```

}

I don't want user `DatasourceBuilder.create.url().password()..` something chain invocation like that,I just want to congiure my sql connection metadata in
application.properties with oneslide.datasource namespce.And try to use the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory Bean,not with tutorial's way in which they
use spring.datasource.* property.
but when i run it datasource debug info is null,there it is digest of exception log:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
>   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>
> : Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when
>   'hibernate.dialect' not set

Help me thanks a lot.

Comment: If you dont want configuration class, just use configuration file...

Comment: I want to configure the data source  with javaconfig,And externaize the data source configuration in custom namespace such as oneslide.datasource.url...in application.properties,given that I will configure multidatasource soon.

Comment: Key confusion is that I use @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="oneslide.datasource")in my code,but it can't load my datasource metadata application.properties

Answer (score 0):

I totally misunderstand spring boot,Maybe.....it autoconfigure all bean,like
LocalContainerEntityManagerfactoryBean!so to use multidatasource,I just need to configure a datasource only,Right???

Answer (score 0):

Your annotation `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="oneslide.datasource")` is asking Sprint to get the info from the external configuration and bind it with the bean you are annotating, i.e. the result produced by the method.

BUT the annotated bean MUST have the properties to receive the configuration values. I.e. it has to have fields and inner objects that replicate the structure of the configurations you are passing (and the setters too).

As example if your config contains something like below:

```
oneslide.datasource.url = some_url
oneslide.datasource.user = usr
oneslide.datasource.password = pw
oneslide.datasource.special.detail = whatever
```

The bean you build should have fields "url", "user" and "password" AND an object "special" with a field "detail", so that Spring can set the values. Simplifying something along `Y = X.getSpecial(); Y.setDetail()` (with null recognition and object creation too, I think to remember).

**If you do nothing...** Spring behind the scene will create a DataSourceProperties bean (that unsurprisingly contains the fields normally used to set up a datasource with the config info under "spring.datasource").
You can get hold of this bean by defining your own bean that gets it as a parameter, like below:

```
public <whatever> getTheD_S_Properties(DataSourceProperties myDataSourceValesFromConfig) {
    ...do something with the bean you got, 
    that contains the values from your config...
}
```

The most common operation, in this case is to just build the datasource yourself, with some logic beyond just assigning the values form the config.

If you need to do nothing special, then let Spring to build the datasource too.
Just sit back and enjoy !  :)